# Flexbox column direction same width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I make my flexbox with column direction children be same width.

JSFiddle Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/6ynofan5/

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="title">Some dummy text here, huh</div>

  <div class="info">
    <div class="text">1</div>
    <div class="text">2</div>
    <div class="text">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.block .title {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.block .info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Div with class .info should be the same width as .title, there should not be fixed width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equalising of widths is managed by `align-items` where the default is `stretch`. In this instance you have over-ridden this and so a wrapper is needed.

Then the two inner divs can be their natural 100% width.

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.title {
  font-size: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: plum;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="title">Some dummy text here, huh</div>

    <div class="info">
      <div class="text">1</div>
      <div class="text">2</div>
      <div class="text">3</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I added align-items: center, cuz they should be in the center of the container, in your answer they are in flex-start position

Comment: Yea, changing HTML is not a problem

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
.block {
display: table;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1mz9f8p0/1/